# Postgresql COALESCE with String Literals does not work as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce

I'm trying to output and label a column total from a rollup.

```
select coalesce(column_1, 'Total') as coalesced_value,     
sum(column_2) as column_sum
from table 
where yada yada
group by rollup(coalesced_value)
order by coalesced_value
```

The query works fine and generates a total as expected, but the column value that I would expect to be 'Total' shows up as [null].

There's a good chance it's probably some lack of understanding on my part, but then there's this that says that [PostgreSQL's COALESCE is non-standard](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_vs_SQL_Standard#COALESCE_on_row_types) and makes me wonder if it's really me.

To quote:

> COALESCE on row types
>
> The spec defines COALESCE(X,Y) as a syntactic transformation to CASE WHEN X IS NOT NULL THEN X ELSE Y END (it leaves open the question of whether X is really evaluated twice by disallowing non-deterministic expressions or expressions with side effects in this context). A consequence of this is that the rather odd rules for null tests of row types are applied.
> PostgreSQL applies only the "is not the null value" test to X. Accordingly, if X is a row value containing null columns, PostgreSQL will return X, while the spec would require returning Y.

(Lovely explanation, right?)

I also ran across some information that indicates that COALESCE data types have to match, otherwise the function fails silently. (!)

I would expect the string literal 'Total' to be interpreted as a varchar, and column_1 is defined in the database as a varchar(12), but at this point I am not sure of much of anything, and any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: That bit in the wiki is talking about "row types" (things like `coalesce(some_row_value, row(1,2,3))`) so it doesn't have anything to do with simple `varchar`s, the text makes more sense when you realize that `X` and `Y` in that context are compound values. Looks like you're getting the string `'[null]'` somewhere in your `column_1` values so everything is working fine and you're being tricked by an odd value in the column (which probably came from a broken application that was writing data to your table). So look at your table and see if you can produce a minimal example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
group by rollup(coalesced_value)
```

You are grouping by the value *after* the `coalesce()` is applied.  Hence, the `rollup` is then generating the `null` value.

Instead, group by the column that is in the data:

```
select coalesce(column_1, 'Total') as coalesced_value,     
       sum(column_2) as column_sum
from table 
where yada yada
group by rollup(column_1)
order by (column_1 is null)::int, -- put the total at the end
         coalesced_value;
```

This explicitly orders the results in the way that you want them.  The results will be what you want without it (I think).  The first part `(column1 is null)::int` is a boolean expression converted to a number.  Null values are true and assigned a value of 1; non-NULL values are assigned a value of 0.  These are first, because the sort is ascending (by default).

Comment: @klin . . . I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: This appears to be the best answer.  Could you please explain the first term of the order by clause? [(geoid is null)::int, coalesced_value]  I'm not that familiar with PostgreSQL notation.

Comment: @TomEE . . . It would not work if any values in `column_1` were after `Total` alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in POSTGRESQL, but I can still provide some insight.  The easiest way would be to simply use a subquery:

```
select coalesce(column_1,'Total') as coalesced_value
,column_sum
from
(
select column_1
,sum(column_2) as column_sum
from table
where yada yada
group by rollup(column_1)
) a
order by coalesced_value;
```

If you want to avoid a subquery, you should be able to use the GROUPING function.  I know this works in Teradata SQL, but after some Googling it appears it should work in POSTGRESQL as well:

```
select case when grouping(column_1) = 1 then 'Total'
else column_1 end as grouping_value
,sum(column_2) as column_sum
from table
where yada yada
group by rollup(column_1)
order by grouping_value;
```